# Is there a way to print the amount in XSL 1.0 template with for loop for below scenario?

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have requirement or logic where the below tag needs to printed with a difference of 100000 with a for loop logic. Please help in XSL 1.0

Scenario 1

```
<Amt>
430000
</Amt>
```

Output required

```
<Amt>100000</Amt>
<Amt>100000</Amt>
<Amt>100000</Amt>
<Amt>100000</Amt>
<Amt>30000</Amt>
```

Scenario 2

```
<Amt>
299999
</Amt>
```

Output required

```
<Amt>100000</Amt>
<Amt>100000</Amt>
<Amt>99999</Amt>
```

Scenario 3

```
<Amt>
23000
</Amt>
```

Output required

```
<Amt>23000</Amt>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such thing as a "for loop" in XSLT 1.0. The result you want can be obtained by calling a recursive named template:

```
<xsl:template name="split-to-lakhs">
    <xsl:param name="amt"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$amt > 100000">
            <Amt>100000</Amt>
            <!-- recursive call -->
            <xsl:call-template name="split-to-lakhs">
                <xsl:with-param name="amt" select="$amt - 100000"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <Amt>
                <xsl:value-of select="$amt"/>
            </Amt>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Demo: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/nbiE1aD

Comment: Hi Michael, Thank you for the great reply and solution. Could you please help in code modification as the requirement was to split in multiple tags as with for each logic 

`Scenario -
<result>
 <Amt>399000</Amt>
</result>


Output Required
<result>
 <Amt>100000</Amt>
</result>
<result>
 <Amt>100000</Amt>
</result>
<result>
 <Amt>100000</Amt>
</result>
<result>
 <Amt>99000</Amt>
</result>`

Comment: The result you show is an XML fragment, not a well-formed XML document. In any case, the adjustment is trivial and you should be able to do it yourself.